# Try/Catch in MSI Installer Script

Tags: c#, windows, installation, windows-installer

I have a Windows Installer prompting a user for MySQL information (server, port, username, password) and would like to make sure the parameters are correct prior to completing the setup.

I have have an Installer project with Custom Actions linked to the Installer Class and am doing my error checking there in the "Install" method. My error occurs at the `catch()` portion.

Any suggestions or comments greatly appreciated.

Edit: When I hit [Next] the installer installs the application and then prompts the MessageBox (if there's an error) but *completes* the installation. I was hoping for it to Rollback and bring up the previous screen.

Edit2: The exception caught from MySqlException is: "Unable to connect any of the specified MySQL hosts," which is correct, but the installer does not return/roll back.

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);

    // parameters from installer
    // generate connection string conStr
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conStr);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

    // open connection and create database
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        // create database
        // create table
        // insert values to test
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
      //I would like this to go back to the prior page
      //where it asks for user input
        MessageBox.Show("There was a problem connecting to the database.");
        this.Rollback(stateSaver); // not working?
    }

    // close connection
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Add a `catch (Exception ex) { }` to catch all generic exceptions - perhaps something else is being thrown?

Comment: Like Josh M. said, it can be helpful to catch all exceptions. Connector/NET might be well throwing IOExceptions. MySqlExceptions are typically server errors send via already established connection, if there was an error establishing connection, something else might be thrown.

Comment: Could you simply rethrow the exception after you did show the messagebxo? By the way this installer from System.Configuration.Install is not in any way related to MSI nor MSI custom actions.

Comment: @Josh M. - I tried adding that with `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` and nothing came up. I also added ArgumentException and InvalidOperationException as I found them in Connector/Net documentation. The only Exception being thrown is the MySqlException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force a rollback of your current installation you can rethrow the exception. you did just display in your messagebox.